# How to use the ifelse function for two conditions combining strings and values?

Tags: r, if-statement

I know there's a lot of questions on the `ifelse` function, but I can't seem to figure out how to make my code to work. I've been inspired by solutions posted in previous questions but I'm still having error messages. Below is a sample of my data:

```
     observed predicted probability results1
1     Head-up   Grazing   0.2727273 NEGATIVE
2     Head-up   Grazing   0.7272727 NEGATIVE
3     Head-up   Grazing   0.7272727 NEGATIVE
4     Head-up   Grazing   0.5454545 NEGATIVE
5     Head-up   Grazing   0.7272727 NEGATIVE
6     Head-up   Grazing   0.4545455 NEGATIVE
7     Head-up Vigilance   0.3636364 NEGATIVE
8     Head-up   Grazing   0.3636364 NEGATIVE
9     Head-up Vigilance   0.3636364 NEGATIVE
10    Unknown   Grazing   0.3636364 NEGATIVE
11     Moving   Head-up   0.4545455 NEGATIVE
12     Moving   Grazing   0.3636364 NEGATIVE
13    Head-up   Grazing   0.4545455 NEGATIVE
14    Head-up   Grazing   0.3636364 NEGATIVE
15    Head-up   Grazing   0.4545455 NEGATIVE
16    Head-up   Grazing   0.3636364 NEGATIVE
17    Head-up   Head-up   0.4545455 POSITIVE
```

In this case, I'd like to create a 5th column `results2` with `ifelse` having two conditions:

1) If `probability` is greater than 0.5 and `results1` is `"POSITIVE"`, I would like `results2` to be `"TRUE"`. If `probability` is lower than 0.5 and `results1` is `"POSITIVE"`, I would like `results2` to be `"FALSE"`.

2) If `probability` is greater than 0.5 and `results1` is `"NEGATIVE"`, I would like `results2` to be `"FALSE"`. If `probability` is lower than 0.5 and `results1` is `"NEGATIVE"`, I would like `results2` to be `"TRUE"`.

I've been using different syntaxes for this, such as:

```
collar$result2<-ifelse(collar$results1=="POSITIVE" & collar$probability>0.5,"TRUE","FALSE"|ifelse(collar$results1=="NEGATIVE" & collar$probability>0.5,"FALSE","TRUE"))
```

I'm getting the error: `Error in ifelse(collar$results1 == "POSITIVE", collar$probability > 0.5,  : 
  unused argument ("FALSE")`

Any help is appreciated!

P.S. If using collar: `$results2<-dplyr::mutate(collar,results2 = case_when( (probability > 0.5 & results1 == "POSITIVE") | (probability < 0.5 & results1 == "NEGATIVE") ~ TRUE, TRUE ~ FALSE) )` I get (sample):

```
> print(collar)
     observed predicted probability results1 results2.observed results2.predicted results2.probability results2.results1
1     Head-up Vigilance   0.2727273 NEGATIVE           Head-up          Vigilance            0.2727273          NEGATIVE
2     Head-up   Grazing   0.7272727 NEGATIVE           Head-up            Grazing            0.7272727          NEGATIVE
3     Head-up   Grazing   0.7272727 NEGATIVE           Head-up            Grazing            0.7272727          NEGATIVE
4     Head-up   Grazing   0.5454545 NEGATIVE           Head-up            Grazing            0.5454545          NEGATIVE
5     Head-up   Grazing   0.7272727 NEGATIVE           Head-up            Grazing            0.7272727          NEGATIVE
6     Head-up   Grazing   0.4545455 NEGATIVE           Head-up            Grazing            0.4545455          NEGATIVE
```

Comment: Please don't quote the TRUE/FALSE to character class.  It is a bool. The issue is that the arguments are not matching.  I think you need `ifelse(collar$results1 == "POSITIVE & collar$probabiliy > 0.5, TRUE, ifelse(collar$results1=="NEGATIVE" & collar$probability>0.5, FALSE, FALSE))`

Comment: Could also do `dplyr::mutate(collar, 
              results2 = case_when(
                (probability > 0.5 & results1 == "POSITIVE") | (probability < 0.5 & results1 == "NEGATIVE") ~ TRUE,
                TRUE ~ FALSE)
              )`, that would shorten and make it more readable, however it would turn every instance of `probability == 0.5` to FALSE, not sure what you'd like to do with that

Comment: @akrun Using `collar$results2<-ifelse(collar$results1 == "POSITIVE" & collar$probabiliy > 0.5, TRUE, ifelse(collar$results1=="NEGATIVE" & collar$probability>0.5, FALSE, TRUE))` (I just corrected the last part of the syntax), I'm getting the following error: `Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, results2, value = logical(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 240` Any idea of what does that mean?

Comment: @arg0naut Using that I'm ending up with a table of 10 columns with headers: `observed`, `predicted`, `probability`, `results1`, `results2.observed`, `results2.predicted`, `results2.probability`, `results2.results1`, `results2.results2`. The column I would like to end up adding is just `results2.results2` which is what I'm looking for. However, if I try: `collarres<-collar[,c("observed","predicted","probability","results1","results2.results2")]` I get the error message: `Error in `[.data.frame`(collar, , c("observed", "predicted", "probability",  : undefined columns selected` Any ideas?

Comment: Then you have a different table than what you've posted, should adjust this

Comment: @arg0naut I've been using exactly the same table. I'm unsure how `mutate` works, but seems like it will output a new column for every column already present the function is looking at. A total of 10 in this case, with the headers I've written in my previous comment. Is it possible to change the name of the headers given by R at least? I've been trying but I will always end up with `"my_assigned_name.R_header_name"`. Or maybe you could help me by using `ifelse` ?

Comment: Just do `dput(yourtablename)` and paste output into your answer, we can see then

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188215/discussion-between-juansalix-and-arg0naut).

Answer (score 0):

You may be better off writing your own function than nesting it within  the ifelse() function.  The following would seem to meet your specifications (note also you may have cases where probability == 0.5; here it will return NA):

```
results2 <- apply(collar,1,function(x)
  {
    if (x["results1"]=="POSITIVE" & x["probability"]>0.5) TRUE
    else if (x["results1"]=="POSITIVE" & x["probability"] < 0.5) FALSE
    else if (x["results1"]=="NEGATIVE" & x["probability"]>0.5) FALSE
    else if (x["results1"]=="NEGATIVE" & x["probability"]<0.5) TRUE
    else NA
  })

collar$results2 <- results2
```